# Duplicate content problems after adding an archive page to the article's post type

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I have changed the url of my blog articles from [www.mysite.com/article](http://www.mysite.com/article) to [www.mysite.com/blog/article](http://www.mysite.com/blog/article),
to achieve this, i have used two functions:

```
  if ( $post_type == "post" ) {
    $args['rewrite'] = array(
      'slug' => 'blog'
    );
  }

  return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'rewrite_posts_custom_post_type_args', 20, 2 );

add_filter('pre_post_link', 'my_change_post_link', 10, 3); 
function my_change_post_link($permalink, $post, $leavename) {   
    if (get_post_type($post) == 'post') {     
        return "/blog" . $permalink;   }   
    return $permalink; 
}
```

it worked, but now i have a duplicate content problem, since both the old url and the new url show the same article. Does anyone know how i can delete the old url content?

Comment: To add /blog to your URLs you just need to go to Settings > Permalinks and type it in there.

Comment: yes, but that changes all the permalinks on the site, i need to change the url structure only for the articles post type

Comment: Anything you add there will only be added to the blog.

Comment: it also gets added to the portfolio for some reason

Comment: If that post type has `with_front` set to `true` it will get added. If you’re not registering that post type yourself, you should be able to use the same method you used to change the posts slug to change it.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you!